# Typescript types checking

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, ecmascript-6

```
let a;
a = 5;
a = "hi";
```

Why this is valid TypeScript code? Are there any settings to stricter that besides «a:number»? If not, then what's the point of using TypeScipt, if you can use JavaScript + vscode //@ts-check?
My tsconfig.json:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": ".",
  "outDir": "build/dist",
  "module": "esnext",
  "target": "es6",
  "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
  "sourceMap": true,
  "allowJs": false,
  "strict": true,
  "jsx": "react",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "rootDir": "src",
  "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
  "noImplicitReturns": true,
  "noImplicitThis": true,
  "noImplicitAny": true,
  "strictNullChecks": true,
  "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
  "noUnusedLocals": true
},
```

Comment: That is completly weird, i agree... it is being infeered as as Any, but you have noImplicityAny...

Comment: Can I ask how typescript is supposed to know it is a number or string? shouldn't you be declaring it to be a number so you do not run into it? `let a: number`

Comment: @epascarello in my opinion there should be error=warning like «a has any type»

Comment: The compiler knows through static flow analisys. After the last line, the variable is always a `string` underneath, even if it disguised as `any`

Answer (score 5):

It works because `noImplicitAny` does not affect variable declarations. If a variable is declared, but it's type is not declared, it is assumed `any`.

This was defined like that, because the compiler, despite the variable being `any` implicitly, can in fact determine its type at every point.

In fact, if you do this:

```
var a;
a = 5;
a.dot(); // error, number does not have a 'dot' property.
a = "hi";
a.foo(); // error, string does not have a 'foo' property.
```

You get an error, indicating that `string` has no property `foo`, or `number` has no property `dot`.

But, if you write:

```
function(b) {
    return b + 2;
}
```

This function, however, indicates an error because there is nothing that hints the compiler about what type `b` holds.

Comment: When did this change? Presumably with better flow analysis? I can remember getting "implicit any" errors for variables and can even get them when using typescript 1.8. For typescript 2.8 and the same code, there is no error as described here.

Comment: I guess i found it: [improved any inference](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#improved-any-inference), typescript 2.1.

Comment: Yes. It changed around 2.1 or so. There was a PR about this. If the type can be determined by flow analisys, then there is not really an implicit `any`, even i f the variable can take any value of any type. As long as the type can be determined for every line of code in whuch it appears, there won't be an error.

Answer (score 3):

> Why this is valid TypeScript code?

To allow backwards compability with javascript. This is completely valid js, so it needs to be valid typescript too. But you can easily opt in typechecking:

```
let a: number;
```

Comment: By the way I cant understand typescript philosophy here. There are almost no differences between TypeScript types checking and raw js with //@ts-checking in VSCode

Comment: That would be true, if the OP didn't have `notImplicitAny` turned on. `notImplicitAny` increases the type safety of your code, but diminishes the compatibility with the existing codebase

Comment: @foxPro well there are interfaces and enums, and the typechecking goes far beyond these simple cases

Comment: @OscarPaz you are right, but the `notImplicitAny` affects function arguments and not variables.

Answer (score 2):

> Why this is valid TypeScript code?

**noImplicityAny** only affects "arguments" not "variables".

Consequently this codes is correct:

```
let a;
a = 'test';
a = 123;
```

But you will get an error, when you want to declare a functions argument:

```
function log(someArg) { // Error : someArg has an implicit `any` type
    console.log(someArg);
}
```

This code would work:

```
function log(someArg: any | string | number) { // Error : someArg has an implicit `any` type
    console.log(someArg);
}
```

TypeScript ensures, that you can use types and validates them, when the variable is in use (eg. as an argument).

[Here you can find the article.](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/options/noImplicitAny.html)